# SharePoint Online 2013/2016 Design Packages without SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, design, design-manager

Is Microsoft still committed to SharePoint Designer? I heard there would be no SPD 2016?

Anybody creating design packages for SPO with something other than SPD? What and how? Anybody doing it manually with plain editor?

Any concerns with custom master pages based on Class Oslo breaking in SPO 2013 and MS constant updates and changes? 2016? Modern Experience updates?

Possible to create custom SPO designs for Modern Experience?

Comment: there's do designer 16 because 2013 works just fine, there was no need to upgrade the client.

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint Designer 2013 works very well for SharePoint Server 2016 and SharePoint Online. And you can continue to use your old branding techniques, if you like. And it really depends of what you're trying to do.

You can use

- **Theming** by uploading a custom *.spcolor file. You can generate the spcolor-file by using the free [SharePoint Color Palette Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182). When uploaded, you just follow the link to "Change the look".
- **Alternative CSS and JavaScript embeded** if Publishing Infrastructure Feature is enabled, which lets you do even more customizations. Simplify it with Node.JS, Yeoman, Gulp and SASS. The step to SPFx is much simpler if you learn the new tools.

[image]

[image]

See more on the video [Learn best practices for customizing and branding SharePoint Team Sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AxN-G56-d4)

- **Traditional custom masterpage** (copy n paste from oslo or seattle).

Answer (score 4):

Is Microsoft still committed to SharePoint Designer?
 *- They are committed to it being supported for SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint Online. There will be no new version of SPD coming out in the future.*

I heard there would be no SPD 2016?
 *- Correct, but SPD2013 works with SP2016.*

Anybody creating design packages for SPO with something other than SPD? 
 *- You can use the Design Manager in SPO or SP2013 to create a Design Package containing Master Pages, Page Layouts Alternate CSS, Display templates and more.*

What and how? Anybody doing it manually with plain editor?
 *- Check out this [tutorial for Design Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822363.aspx)*

Any concerns with custom master pages based on Class Oslo breaking in SPO 2013 and MS constant updates and changes? 
 *- Yes, only create custom Master Pages if absolutely necessary. My advice is to use CSS and JavaScript in place of a custom Master Page. See [this post](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2015/01/custom-master-pages-and-web-templates-in-office-365--thoughts.html) for more advice.*

2016? 
 *- If you are using SP2016 OnPrem, go wild with master pages. You control when the feature pack gets installed and can test before launching any changes that could impact your custom master pages.*

Modern Experience updates?
 *- There are no master pages for the Modern Experience.*

Possible to create custom SPO designs for Modern Experience?
 *- Presently we have very little customization options for the Modern Experience, but they are on the road map.*